# Asp.net and OAuth simple example without existing Library

Tags: asp.net, oauth

I try to get a request token from Twitter OAuth and I always received a server error 401 when I try to get the response. I don't want to used an existing library because I try to learn Oauth and maybe build my own library. This is my simple code :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

StringBuilder sbParams = new StringBuilder();
sbParams.Append("OAuth ");
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_consumer_key={0},", "[COMSUMERKEY]");
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method={0},", "PLAINTEXT");
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_signature={0},", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("[COMSUMER_SECRET]&"));
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp={0},", ((int)(DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds).ToString());
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce={0},", "asdfalkjpoijwpeonpoaisudfnpowieuyfpasosdfdn");
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_version={0},", "1.0");
sbParams.AppendFormat("oauth_callback={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()));

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", sbParams.ToString());

// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#http_codes You know these

> ```
> HTTP 401 Unauthorized
>     Invalid Consumer Key
>     Invalid / expired Token
>     Invalid signature
>     Invalid / **used nonce
> ```

The "used nonce" thing may be a problem. You need to generate a random string. From  http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#nonce

> A nonce is a random string, uniquely generated for **each** request

---

Onto the serious business. You are not supposed to transmit your consumer secret, once you ever received it! Many OAuth libraries have a

```
request_request_token(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
```

Despite appearances, the consumer_secret is **never transmitted**. It is used at client-side, for verification of server's response. (A similar verification occurs at server-side too)

And you dont put in **any** static values for signing requests. From http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#signing_process

> ```
> All Token requests and Protected Resources requests MUST be signed by the Consumer and verified by the Service Provider.
> ```

---

Bottomline: do read the http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/ article to see how the protocol works. And choose a hands-on OAuth library that doesnt abstract too much details (The oauth-php library I used came with SQL tables and managed data stores and session memory by itself).